# How to resolve LWC1010: Failed to resolve entry for module

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to add LWC child component in parent getting LWC1010: Failed to resolve entry for module
My component name is aBHFLSourceLookup

```
<c-a-bhfl-source-lookup-lwc></c-a-bhfl-source-lookup-lwc>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. We need more details. Can you show the child LWC's class name and show how you are trying to reference this in your parent component? Remember that LWC names are converted to kebab-case using a specific process. If your child class ends, e.g. "...LookupLWC" then the name becomes "...-lookup-l-w-c". Please [edit] the question to add the detail (do NOT reply in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the class name `aBHFLSourceLookup` to kebab-case should result in `c-a-b-h-f-l-source-lookup` for use in the parent component template.

Comment: The moral of the story: don't use all caps in your component name, because it makes the markup look virtually unreadable.